# Single or multiple files per mapper in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Does a mapper process multiple files at the same time or a mapper can only process a single file at a time? I want to know the  default behaviour

Comment: You can use the CombineFileInputFormat to process many small files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Typical Mapreduce jobs follow one input split per mapper by default.
- If the file size is larger than the split size (i.e., it has more
  than one input split), then it is multiple mappers per file.
- It is one file per mapper if the file is not splittable like a `Gzip`
  file or if the process is `Distcp` where file is the finest level of granularity.

Comment: I see, so I think an input slip can have data from multiple files right? So that means a single mapper can process multiple files at the same time.

Comment: No, Splitting is done at file level. Each file will have a minimum of one input split, and no split can be comprised of more than one file. If you have 2 files, one  192MB and the other 32MB, the split size being 128MB, the result will be 3 (2+1) input splits, this will run 3 map tasks. Though the second split of the larger file is lesser than the split size, it does not merge with the split of other files.

Comment: So if the split is done at file level and no split can be comprised of multipe files that mean one mapper will only have the data for single file? One mapper will only work for the data of one file, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the default behaviour. Unless you are using CombineFileInputFormat. This fileformat will combine multiple small files into one bigger file before splitting. Then it is not assured that one mapper will work only on data of one file. If going with default behaviour, your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the definition of [FileInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) you will see that on the top it has three methods:

**addInputPath(JobConf conf, Path path)** -  Add a Path to the list of inputs for the map-reduce job. So it will pick up all files in catalog but not the single one, as you say

**addInputPathRecursively(List result, FileSystem fs, Path path, PathFilter inputFilter)** - Add files in the input path recursively into the results.

**addInputPaths(JobConf conf, String commaSeparatedPaths)** - Add the given comma separated paths to the list of inputs for the map-reduce job

Operating these three methods you can easily setup any multiple input you want. Then [InputSplits](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) of your InputFormat start to spliting this data among the mapper jobs. The Map-Reduce framework relies on the InputFormat of the job to:

- Validate the input-specification of the job.
- Split-up the input file(s) into logical InputSplits, each of which is then assigned to an individual Mapper.
- Provide the RecordReader implementation to be used to glean input records from the logical InputSplit for processing by the Mapper.

So technically single mapper will process its own part only which can contain the data from several files. But for each particular format you should look into InputSplit to understand how data will be distributed accross the mappers.

Comment: No, Single mapper cannot process multiple files at a time. Single mapreduce job can process multiple files at a time. All this path definition pertains to the job and not to the task.

Comment: @franklinsijo We probably have misunderstanding about what OP means in processing multiple files at a time. I mean that it can process multiple files from input. This total input will be split into parts and each mapper will process its own part, but not several parts at a time. That is what i mean in my answer.

Comment: Yes " not at a time", you might have to change that part in your answer. OP wants to know about the mapper not the job itself `Does a mapper process multiple files`? .

Comment: @franklinsijo Thanks for the tip. Probably it was really confusing and not clear. I updated the answer with more proper explanation.

Comment: So if the split is done at file level and no split can be comprised of multipe files that mean one mapper will only have the data for single file? One mapper will only work for the data of one file, right?

Comment: @user3396729 Yes, the split will represent the whole file by default. Especially for small files it just does not make sense to granular them more as the cost of scheduling MapReduce job would be much bigger then the actual transferring and execution.  But this behavior could vary depending on the inputFormat implementation so for each particular Format you should refer to its implementation docs.